# Error 500 occurs when accessing the servlet class

Tags: java, servlets, get, request

When trying to launch the application, error 500 (HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error) appears when it comes to accessing the ControllerServlet, the code of which is presented below

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (req.getParameter("x") == null || req.getParameter("y") == null || req.getParameter("r") == null || req.getParameter("key") == null) {
            req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        }
        else{
            getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("AreaChecker").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (req.getParameter("key").equals("update")) {
            getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("AreaChecker").forward(req, resp);
        }
        else{
            req.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("Controller").forward(req, resp);
        }
    }

}
```

**Text of error:**

Type Exception Report

Message Класс [com.example.ControllerServlet] не является сервлетом

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Класс [com.example.ControllerServlet] не является сервлетом
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.ControllerServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet (com.example.ControllerServlet is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @7abda5a1; jakarta.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @37afeb11)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

**Version of Tomcat: 10.0.14**

My question is: how to avoid this error and what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.ControllerServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet
```

here:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

and here:

> Version of Tomcat: 10.0.14

You have a `javax` servlet in a servlet container that implements version 5 of the servlet specification which is now in the `jakarta` namespace.

You need to extend your servlet from the `jakarta` packages, not `javax`.

See the following links for more details:

- https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet
- https://dzone.com/articles/jakarta-ee-without-javax-the-world-wont-end-this-time-either